# pefile How do I nullify the first 8 bytes of a file?

Tags: python

How do I nullify the first 8 bytes of a file?

this example does not work:

```
import pefile
pe = pefile.pe(In)
pe.set_dword_at_rva(0,0)
pe.set_dword_at_rva(0,4)
pe.write(Out)
pe.close()
```

How i can rename import functions in the file?
this example does not work:

```
for entry in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:
  print entry.dll
  for imp in entry.imports:
     imp.name = 'NewIMports'
pe.write(Out)
```

sorry for my english

Comment: Is it necessary to use `pefile` for this?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Raises an exception? (If so, please give the exception, with traceback.) Seems to work but has no effect? Seems to work but has the wrong effect? Does what you wanted, but now the program won't run? Collects dole checks?

Comment: Also, why are you using `set_dword_at_rva` instead of `set_dword_at_offset` if you specifically want offset 0? (And, for that matter, why `set_dword` twice instead of just `set_qword`?)

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to use the standard way (i. e. not using `pefile`) of doing this:

```
with file('filename.bla', 'wr+') as f:
  f.write('\0' * 8)
```

Comment: So how are you going to rename imports that way?

Comment: It looks like this question is actually two different questions.

Comment: @Will: Agreed. But I think any answer to the second question will also solve the first, while avoiding the first question this way won't help at all with the second.

Comment: Meanwhile, why are you using `file` instead of `open`, and what is that `'wr+'` mode supposed to do?

Comment: @abernet, the part about the renaming imports somehow didn't enter my mind (must have just missed it).  `'wr+'` just opens in the file for reading and writing, and that simultaneously.  I just use it to state *give me total control, don't do silly things automatically like truncating after writing* etc.  Using `file` instead of `open` is non-canon, agreed.  But it does the same, and I find it more intuitive to use the `file()` constructor to create a file.  But feel free to use `open()` instead.

Comment: @Alfe: It sounds like what you're really looking for there is the `'r+'` mode. Specifying `'wr+'` is redundant and works only by accident. See [docs for `open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for the list of supported modes.

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple problems with your code, but I'm not sure which ones are causing whatever problems you're experiencing (since you haven't explained the problems).

First, you want to set the first 8 bytes to 0, but you're using `set_dword_at_rva` rather than `set_dword_at_offset`. An RVA ("Relative Virtual Address") is the offset in memory to the runtime address of a section (whatever that runtime address ends up being). An offset is the offset on disk from the start of the file. If that's what you want, use that. (While you're at it, the `qword` functions are the way to set 8 bytes at a time. Using `dword` instead can't cause any problems except for endianness, which can't possibly matter for just setting to 0… but still, why make it harder on yourself?)

So:

```
pe = pefile.pe(In)
pe.set_qword_at_offset(0, 0)
```

---

Meanwhile, if you're modifying arbitrary strings within the file, while `pefile` can make room for them, it does not adjust any other headers that need to be adjusted to compensate. See "Notes about the write support" in [the docs](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/wiki/UsageExamples) for details. So, `imp.name = 'NewIMports'` may work, but generate a broken PE, if the old name was shorter.

On top of that, renaming all of the imports to have the same name will *definitely* generate a broken PE.